# .htaccess URL rewrite access

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some help. This is the original link

```
 http://tester.local/adm/index_pub.php?ch=feondi-event
```

I want it to be access like this

```
 http://tester.local/feondi_event
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained). You can't do this with mod_rewrite anyway. You are supposed to manually handle the text extraction from the rewritten url. You are obviously missing a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /adm/index_pub.php?ch=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^feondi_event$ /adm/index_pub.php
```

Comment: thanks for responds. but as i test it is not working.

Comment: Updated it please check now

Answer (score 0):

This does not use `.htaccess`, but works as well:

```
<?php
if($_GET['ch'] == 'feondi-event') {
    header("Location: http://tester.local/feondi_event");
}
?>
```